# Gettting the host name of a Client making calls over WCF?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Is there a way to get the host name of the cleint making the call to a net.tcp binding in WCF. I'm trying to Diagnose an issue and I'd like to find out which client is sending me the message which is causing it.

I've tried:

```
OperationContext.Current.Channel.RemoteAddress.Uri.AbsoluteUri
```

But that only seems to give me a generic schema rather than a host name/ip address.

Answer (score 6):

I think RemoteAddress is only valid for duplex channels. What you need is the RemoteEndpointMessageProperty, like:

```
var remp = OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties[RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name] as RemoteEndpointMessageProperty;
string addr = remp.Address;
// do a DNS lookup or whatever from here if you want the hostname
```